# ARM Cortex simulator that allows single stepping etc

Tags: arm, simulator

Does anyone know of an ARM simulator program that I can use to try some assembler programming, e.g. running opcodes, watching register values change etc.?  Can be either Windows or Linux based.

Thank you,
Fred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one for the thumb instruction set, search for thumbulator at github.com.  Qemu has a number of arm variations supported.  mame has some arm support.  gdb and others have the armulator from arm.  I wrote mine to get better visibility, visibility from the others perhaps with the exception of gdb and whatever it might show, is sparse.   I dont remember what to search for but there is a verilog behavior model for the ARM on a university site that probably gives the best visibility of all.  (use verilator or icarus verilog, create .vcd files and use gtkwave to view them).